# Updating Listview

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an android application similar to Facebook android application. On the timeline screen I have list of posts , user can like or comment any post. When user like a post, to highlight the like button I took the object from array , change its liked status and notify adapter so like button gets highlighted.
If user clicks on a Post a detail screen opens up. In detail screen user also has option to like the post. Now my problem is, if user like a post from detail screen and went back, he should be at the same position in the list and like button of the post on that position should be highlighted.
I tried to do it by starting detail activity with StartActivityForResult() method and passed the selected object. In onActivityResult() method I am getting back the modified object from detail Activity. I replaced the original post object by the modified object in array and notify the adapter.
I am not sure about my logic that its a good one or not. I need a better solution to do this. I will be very thankful to any good suggestion.

Comment: Why don't you modify the object more permanently?

Comment: Could you post your adapter?

Comment: Permanently? I also has an other option that is when I come back to Posts list screen I call the API to load posts again. but I dont want to call the posts api again on coming back. Thats why I want to have a change locally

Answer (score 1):

onActivityResult() would be just the right answer but you are not finishing your activity but pressing back/home button instead. So in this case no information is being passed to the parent activity.

A solution that comes to my mind is modifying your objects more permanentle via [sharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or some [ORM](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/). But it may be something unpleasant being collecting data from memory in every movement of your app.

What I suggest is transforming your detailActivity to a detailFragment. It would be easier to pass information to the parent activity. In this case the activity that has the full list would start the fragment passing the single element that has been clicked. After that, you would implement a interface to comunicate with the parent activity and in this case the main list would always be updated correctly.

This method requires a very long explanation, too much in fact. I would point out the main steps in order to give a starting point for researching.

1. [Create a fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) similar to your detailActivity. It needs a declaration of the proper [interface](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to communicate with the activity.
2. Make your activity to implement the interface and override its definition. This function will handle like button being pressed. So is it here where you need to update the main arrayList.
3. [Change](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) one main fragment with detail fragment when an item is clicked.

I hope it helps you to find final solution for your code.

PD: I found [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) url that may content the whole process, just very well detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. onActivityResult() is a good implementation for activity to activity communication.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not wrong.

But if you want it to be simple, you might want to try some third part library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), it could help you to deliver your message between components like activities easily.

In your case, a **StickyEvent** is helpful.